# xstream: map object to xml excluding one field

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I have a class to map into XML using xstream.

Class is having 5 fields. Out of these five fields I want one field that should not be mapped to xml and only four fields should be mapped into XML.

E.g

```
public class Person {
  private String firstname;
  private String lastname;
  private String phone;
  // ... constructors and methods
}
```

When this class is mapped I want XML like this i.e. **no phone number**

```
<person>
  <firstname>Joe</firstname>
  <lastname>Walnes</lastname>
</person>
```

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 3):

```
xstream.omitField(Person.class, "phone");
```

or in annotation

Answer (score 0):

With classic Java code:

```
XStreamMarshaller marshaller = ... //Get your XStreamMarshaller
marshaller.getXStream().omitField(Person.class, "phone");
```

With annotation:

```
@XStreamOmitField
private String phone;
```

For the second case, you must call `marshaller.getXStream().autodetectAnnotations(true);` or `marshaller.getXStream().processAnnotations(Person.class);` to be sure that annotations are used.

Comment: it depends on your version because on 1.4.X and befor we can simply do    XStream xstream=new XStream(new DomDriver); and so use xtsream object directly, what is the plus to use XStreamMarchaller please ?thanks !